# javascript : text box with default value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text boxes with default values, I am not able to enter values into them when i am trying to enter, I have to first delete the existing value using delete key then only i can enter.

I want to enter values and on tab change it should change for the other box as well, currently it is changing focus but I cannot enter values into them.

```
<input type="text" name="namebox" id="{concat('textboxvalue', position())}" value="{@proj}" style="font-size:10px;padding:0px;height:15px;width:90px;text-align:right;"/>
```

`@proj`: values coming from database

Thanks,
Ani

Comment: <input type="text" name="tproj" id="{concat('txtboxAdjustment', position())}" value="{@proj}" style="font-size:10px;padding:0px;height:15px;width:90px;text-align:right;" />

Comment: <input type="text" name="tproj" id="{concat('txtboxAdjustment', position())}" value="{@proj}" style="font-size:10px;padding:0px;height:15px;width:90px;text-align:right;" />

@proj - is default value coming from database

there are multiple text boxes i am creating in loop

Comment: @Animesh Put it *in* your question

Answer (score 5):

You can use placeholders in the input tags and textarea tags:

```
<input type='text' placeholder='Default text here' />
<textarea placeholder='Default text here'></textarea>
```

Then use fallback with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var defaultVal = "Default text here";
    $("input, textarea").val(defaultVal).on("focus", function(){
        if($(this).val() == defaultVal){
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }).on("blur", function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).val(defaultVal);
        }
    });

});
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/EZexQ/1/

Comment: The newest versions of all major browsers support it: http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder It's worth to mention though.

Comment: You could also replace `defaultVal` with the value of the placeholder attribute using `var defaultVal = $("input").attr("placeholder");`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at [this css-trick article](http://css-tricks.com/textarea-tricks/).
It has an example with html5 placeholder attribute with jquery fallback.

```
function elementSupportsAttribute(element, attribute) {
  var test = document.createElement(element);
  if (attribute in test) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};  


if (!elementSupportsAttribute('textarea', 'placeholder')) {
  // Fallback for browsers that don't support HTML5 placeholder attribute
  $("#example-three")
    .data("originalText", $("#example-three").text())
    .css("color", "#999")
    .focus(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        if (this.value == $el.data("originalText")) {
          this.value = "";
        }
    })
    .blur(function() {
      if (this.value == "") {
          this.value = $(this).data("originalText");
      }
    });
} else {
  // Browser does support HTML5 placeholder attribute, so use it.
  $("#example-three")
    .attr("placeholder", $("#example-three").text())
    .text("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the focus. Just remove the values. 
Following is sample code in jquery. Can be done with plain javscript though.

```
<input value=10>
<input value=20>
<input value=30>

$('input').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).val('')
})
```

Comment: if the user enters a value in an input, then he refocuses the same, the value entered already will be cleared out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DOM property called [defaultValue](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp) for input elements. Am giving this solution as the placeholders do not work in older browsers.

```
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="John"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Doe"><br>
```

In your jQuery, it can be accessed by `prop('defaultValue')`
So try this.

```
$('input').focus(function(){
 if($(this).val() == $(this).prop('defaultValue'))
    $(this).val('');
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    $(this).val($(this).prop('defaultValue'));
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/83Mts/)